# GCP - Image creation from VMDK fails - TranslateFailed: error: internal_parse_mountable: internal_parse_mountable_stub

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Trying to import a VMware VMDK that uses LVM and after about an hour and 15 minutes after chewing on it GCP throws the error:

[import-image]: Error running workflow: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-image-translate-disk-grlr1": "TranslateFailed: error: internal_parse_mountable: internal_parse_mountable_stub: /dev/centos_system/root: No such file or directory"

Is there anything I can do with my original machine to fix this or is there something in the platform I need to do?

Comment: Is this a boot disk or a secondary data disk? If a boot disk, not supported. See the answer from @Mahboob for a link. If a data disk, what is the boot sector format? If MBR then you can manually import the the disk to an additional persistent disk provided that the LVM volume is entirely on the same disk. Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files#source_vm_requirements) the boot disk must not span multiple physical disk i.e; a  boot disk is in LVM not supported.